# Point in a plane closest to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Suppose $a_1$ and $a_2$ are orthogonal unit vectors in $R^5$.

Where P is the projection matrix.

$P = a_1a_1^T + a_2a_2^T$

If $a_3$ is in $R^5$
, what combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$ is closest to $a_3$?

This has a simple solution. Just multiply matrix P with $a_3$

So we should have a result $a_1a_1^Ta_3 + a_2a_2^Ta_3$

But [here](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring11/Exam2S.pdf) the answer is given $a_1^Ta_3a_1 + a_2^Ta_3a_2$ . No process is stated though. Only the answer is given.

However $a^Ta$ equal to $aa^T$ as explained [Product of a vector and its transpose (Projections)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853808/product-of-a-vector-and-its-transpose-projections)

Note when we are mentioning transpose we mean a vector in Matrix form.
So I think that solution is incorrect. So my question is which solution is correct? And if the one given in the MIT link is correct ,then why?

Note: I know dot product is commutative but not it's matrix form.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $a_1^{T}a_3$ and $a_2^{T}a_3$ are scalars? So, actually there are some parentheses missing in the proposed solution.

Comment: @trancelocation wow, thank you. I got my answer. I didn't notice it. Before ,now I understand the two things are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed to by @trancelocation, i didn't notice it before. Both the tings are same.

$a_1^Ta_3$ and $a_2^Ta_3$ are scalars.

So we have $a_1(a_1^Ta_3) + a_2(a_2^Ta_3)=(a_1^Ta_3)a_1 + (a_2^Ta_3)a_2$

Not deleting the question for future reference, if anyone else gets stuck.